# Encoding error with Japanese text using nanoc

Tags: html, character-encoding, nanoc

I'm having trouble getting Japanese text to display properly on a website compiled using nanoc. I have the following markup in an HTML file, which is not going through any filters or layouts upon compilation:

```
<a class="push_button blue" href="./ja">
  日本語
</a>
```

and I saved the file with UTF-8 encoding and included `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `head` of the HTML document.

But the final markup produced by nanoc in the output folder is:

```
<a class="push_button blue" href="./ja">
  µùÑµ£¼Φ¬₧
</a>
```

I'm not sure if this problem is specific to nanoc or if it's a general text encoding issue, but could someone suggest where this might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying nanoc with Pali language and this helped me:

```
#lib/default.rb
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Comment: Thanks! The first line broke my nanoc compile, but the second line alone solved the problem.